# C3.JS : show only one line on load by default for line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

I am using C3.js for multiple line graph.
I have around 2 line at the start but out of those two, i want to show only one and hide another one.
I have used   `chart.show('data1')`
but without any luck.
Please help.

Another question is , can we have drilling charts in C3.js ?

Thanks.

The code :

```
<html>
  <head>
 <link href="./c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
<script src="./d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="./c3.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </body>
<script>
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: [
            ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06'],
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 250],
            ['data245', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350]
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d'
            }
        }
    }
});

chart.show('data1');


</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default all the lines will be visible. so hide all the lines first and then show the line you want to see

```
chart.hide(['data1', 'data245']);
chart.show('data1');
```

If you have only 2 lines and want hide one then

```
chart.hide('data245');
```

check the [show](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-show) and [hide](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-hide) api

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8j6j4oh4/13/) implementing the above.